# Your system folder path does not appear to be set correctly. Please open the following file and correct this: index.php

Tags: codeigniter

When I enter my web address in the browser it showing error like this.

> Your system folder path does not appear to be set correctly. Please open the following file and correct this: index.php

Please anyone give me the solution.

Comment: Have you change your system folder to something else??

Comment: Nope. I have not changed anything.

Comment: Please provide your File structure by edit your question..

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/pVPy1ZC.png

Comment: Your System folder is not there.

Comment: Where it will present.?

Comment: You have to have system folder in your structure. I think you rename it or not upload it.

Comment: The error message itself is the solution ...

Comment: Are you using hostinger's free web hosting...

Answer (score 17):

check your index.php file like the error said and look for $system_path and $application_folder. Those folders must exist in the root of your application, if you delete them(which you shouldn't do) or renamed them, it will cause that error

```
$system_path = 'system';
$application_folder = 'application';
```

Answer (score 10):

Check if the required `application` and `system` folders exist. I had the same problem after deleting the "*system*" folder

Answer (score 6):

Check your permission.  The web server user may not have permissions to read everything.

Answer (score 1):

When you copying the project files from one system to other some files are missing. so copy once again properly and refresh the page with the same url you will get.

Comment: re-uploaded system folder and problem was solved, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your project don't have a system folder, if you are using composer try to run composer install on your project root folder. In my case its the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but for me, it was the first time installing code ignitor using composer. When I copied the files from vendor/codeignitor/ to my web root then everything worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

please check your system folder in root directory. I think it is not exist. I was getting same issue and i have fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

1. check your index.php file like the error said and look for $system_path and $application_folder. Those folders must exist in the root of your application, if you delete them(which you shouldn't do) or renamed them, it will cause that error

   $system_path = 'system';
   $application_folder = 'application';
2. Change the php version to 5.6 (if its 7.2+ changing it to 5.6 , worked for me)

Answer (score 0):

This is because your system path is missing

1. Go to `index.php` file
2. Check the `$system_path ='path'` variable
3. Check the `$application_folder ='path'` variable
4. Probably the folder path missing or **Renamed which you shouldnt do**
5. If your using composer `composer install` will create the system folder path
6. If not the case you have to re-install Codeignitor

> Remember : Never ever modify or rename system files

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have a vendor folder, if not run `composer install`