# Your application folder path does not appear to be set correctly error in codeigniter

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I get a error called "Your application folder path does not appear to be set correctly. Please open the following file and correct this: index.php". I use the site within a folder in main domain. My .htaccess file is as follows, if required.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

############################################
## enable rewrites

# For security reasons, Option followsymlinks cannot be overridden.
#    Options +FollowSymLinks
    Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    RewriteEngine on

############################################
## you can put here your magento root folder
## path relative to web root


############################################
## workaround for HTTP authorization
## in CGI environment

    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

############################################
## always send 404 on missing files in these folders

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(media|skin|js)/

############################################
## never rewrite for existing files, directories and links

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

############################################
## rewrite everything else to index.php

    RewriteRule .* index.php [L]

</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_security.c>
    # Turn off mod_security filtering.  SMF is a big boy, it does not need its hands held.
    SecFilterEngine Off

    # The below probably isn't needed, but better safe than sorry.
    SecFilterScanPOST Off
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Are you using xampp? wamp? etc.

Comment: When you say `I use the site within a folder in main domain` do you mean like a sub domain?

Comment: Yes it is like subdomain. But it is actually not a subdomain. It is a normal folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should post also your 'config' file, usually this come from a `base_url` or something messing up. My working site with CI uses:

```
$config['base_url']         = 'http://yourUrl.com/';
$config['index_page']           = '';
$config['uri_protocol']     = 'REQUEST_URI';
$config['url_suffix']           = '';
```

The .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    #Add www.
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.yourUrl.com [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://.yourUrl.com/$1 [L,R=301]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^core.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

And all works fine. You could check with your own config/htaccess file.

From here: [Your system folder path does not appear to be set correctly. Please open the following file and correct this: index.php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26113001/your-system-folder-path-does-not-appear-to-be-set-correctly-please-open-the-fol) and [CodeIgniter CLI giving system_path error "path does not appear to be set correctly."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10353611/codeigniter-cli-giving-system-path-error-path-does-not-appear-to-be-set-correct)

> The solution was to leave the $system_path blank...
>
> $system_path = '';
>
> you can try this instead:
>
> $system_path = './system';

Some people also solved this with setting permissions to CI folder:

> 1. set the project folder permission to 755. Eg. sudo chmod 755 /var/www/myCIproject/

And last, for shared servers/folders:

https://serverfault.com/questions/371739/putting-folders-above-public-html-in-a-shared-hosting-environment

Answer (score 0):

You'll notice in codeIgniter that there is a 'system' directory.

Navigate to your index.php file and go to $system_path and set it to that that path.

I noticed this today when I moved my index file from the codeIgniter directory into the root. You will also find that it will follow up with the applications directory. I found my directories in the same location (codeIgniter root). Once I replaced the path it worked well.